# How does this find state actually work in moving a file up one directory?

Tags: find, bash-scripting, sh, mv, string-manipulation

Can someone explain how the string manipulation in this find statement actually works? My head is about to explode trying to figure it out. :-o

From: [UNIX shell scripting: how to recursively move files up one directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/187866/unix-shell-scripting-how-to-recursively-move-files-up-one-directory/187879#187879?newreg=913c16696dba471e9cb3c5401c41ea85)

```
find ".mp3" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}/.."' sh {} \;
```

The above line moves all files with the suffix `.mp3` up one directory exactly, which is exactly what I want. Wanting to learn more about shell scripting, I'm trying to understand (well, pretty much everything) in the above statement.

The `mv` statement with the `$1` and `${1%/*}/..`

Why the `sh {}` at the end? Why two `sh`s as well?

Any breakdown of the syntax would be great. I've looked at Bash Manipulation docs and I am pretty confused especially about the `"$1" "${1%/*}/.."` part.

Comment: "Why two `sh`s as well?" – Recently I have explained this (in comments) twice; and this is only "recently". Answering this part of your question would be the nth time for me (this doesn't mean you did something wrong). Therefore I created a separate [question](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690) and answered it decently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that does not work as you stated. It will find only the regular file `.mp3` (not all files with that extension) or, if `.mp3` is a directory, recursively look inside it, finding all regular files below it. You could use `-name "*.mp3"` instead to find all .mp3 regular files below your directory.

Now, the command in the answer you referred is

```
find A -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}/.."' sh {} \;
```

and is allegedly used for the **"standard `find`"**, which is the POSIX `find`, not the GNU `find` you probably have in your system. There are some differences between them, so let the [POSIX `find` manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) guide us here.

The command finds regular files recursively, starting from directory `A`, or, if there is no such directory, it looks for regular file `A` in the current directory.

Now the complicated part. According to the manual, the `-exec` option is of the form

```
-exec utility_name [argument ...] ;
```

See that `sh` is used as `utility_name`. `sh -c` means "execute the following string", which is

`mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}/.."`

- `$1` is the found file, provided by `{}` .
- `$0` is the second `sh` (aha!), so this `sh` here is really doing nothing, just a placeholder.
- `${1%/*}/..` means: fetch `$1`, delete the shortest `/*` match from the end of it (which is slash + its basename), append `/..` to the result, and the final result is its parent directory! For example, `A/B/Music/x.mp3` undergoes this transformation: `A/B/Music/x.mp3` → `A/B/Music` → `A/B/Music/..` → `A/B`.

Therefore, at the end you got a neat POSIX way to move up that file using `find`.

---

More on the `%` symbol that showed up (and also its friend `#`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952009